# Kendo UI - Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, wcf, kendo-ui

```
Error - Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

[image: exact issue error]
    Platform - Icenium.

We are using Remote Service - `http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/json` that will get the data. I attached the format in data received from the service.
[image: return format of data]

Here's my code:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    schema: {
        data: "d"
    },
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/json",
            dataType: "jsonp", // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
            data: {
                id: "4"
            },
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
        },
        change: function () {
            alert('called');
            var data = this.data();
            console.log(data.length); // displays "77"
            debugger;
            $('#txtJson').val(data[0].name);
        }

    }
});

$("#submitButton").click(function () {
    dataSource.read();
    var data = dataSource.data();
    console.log(data.length);
});
```

Here's my service code -

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json?id={id}")
        ]
    List<Person> JSONData(string id);
```

Q 1) How to solve this error - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token`, am I missing something?

Q 2) After clicking on button I'm calling `dataSource.read()`, after that `dataSource.data().length` is getting 0. I think this should be handle in `dataSource.bind(change:function())` . However, After `dataSource.read()` change function is not firing.

Comment: You did not include the images!

Comment: I've added the images. I hope you are clear with what I'm looking for. I've also specified the data being return from service in the image. Thanks,

Comment: Did you realize that you are not returning JSONP but a JSON? That is the reason for the "unexpected token" error.

Comment: Thank you Sir for pointing me to the right direction. I changed my wcf service and now it returns data in response to kendoui callback. Here's data now return from service - 
`jQuery191004038987937383354_1369147742213({"JSONDataResult":[{"id":"4","name":"temp4"},{"id":"4","name":"temp24"}]});`

But still I am not clear with my 2nd question. i.e. dataSource.data() 's length is getting 0 after dataSource.read() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have fixed the problem with JSON vs JSONP, the data is still empty because you are not saying in `datasource.schema` that data is actually inside an element of the received JSON called `JSONDataResult`.

The `schema` should be:

```
schema: {
    data: "JSONDataResult"
},
```

You can add a parse function to schema for debugging what you get:

```
schema : {
    parse: function(response) {
        console.log("parse");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
        debugger;
        return response.JSONDataResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried with schema but no luck, length is undefined. Under the dataSource._pristine property, I did see my data. What could be the issue here?

http://imageshack.us/f/826/lengthundefined.png/

Comment: try defining a `schema.parse` function that shows what you receive. See my edit.

Comment: It worked perfect very well. Thank you :).
After, dataSource.read(), schema parse function fired and then it did stringify and then I got the data in dataSource.data().

One last question - After dataSource.read(), why does not datasource's change event fire?